# Split a .txt file in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, lines

I want to implement a program that reads a file (i.e. `.txt`) and saves the file in an array (I have done this). Then I want to have a 2-dimensional array where I save only the words for every line.

For example if the file contains two lines with two words in every line I want in `array[0][0]` the first word of the first line and in `array[0][1]` to have the second word of the first line, etc.

I have the following code:

```java
for (int i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
    String[] channels = aryLines[i].split(" ");

    System.out.println("line " + (i+1) + ": ");

    for (int j=0; j < channels.length; j++){
        System.out.println("word " + (j+1) + ": ");
        System.out.println(channels[j]);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

where the `aryLines` contatins all the lines but I didn't find a solution that performs what I described.

Comment: What do you want to do about punctuation? If a word ends in a full stop does that word have a full stop on it? Is the full stop a new word? Maybe you have n o punctuatin at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your `1-D` array is: -

```
String[] lines = new String[10];
```

You first need to declare an array of array: -

```
String[][] words = new String[lines.length][];
```

Then iterate over it, and for each line, split it and assign it to inner array: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = lines[i].split("\\s+");
}
```

---

Now, **the problem will be**, not all words are separated by just `space`. They also have many punctuation that you need to consider. I would leave it to you to split it on all the punctuation.

For e.g.: -

```
"This line: - has word separated by, : and -"
```

Now, you would need to find all the punctuation used in your sentence.

---

**One thing which you can do** is use a `Regex` to match a pattern for words only, if you are not sure about what all `punctuation` are used in your line. And add each matched word to an arraylist.

```
"\\w+"  // this regex will match one or more characters forming words
```

Let's see it working in the above example: -

```
    String str = "This line: - has word separated by, : and -";
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        words.add(matcher.group());
    }

    System.out.println(words);
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[This, line, has, word, separated, by, and]
```

You can use this approach in your above loop that I posted.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Every word is seperated with the same character so it is not a problem. It works fine!!! I'd like to ask what this means: "split("\\s+")"

Comment: `\\s` means space. `+` after that is a quantifier, meaning `one or more`. So, `\\s+` means split on `one or more space`. This will handle two words seprated by more than one space.

Comment: Thank you again!!! So the "\\w+" checks in a String if there are special characters and not letters?

Comment: @kostaspapadopoulos.. No actually its opposite. `\\w+` matches just words (alphabets). Again one or more. And as soon as it finds any non-word character, like punctuation or whitespace, it stops matching, and then we just print the matched word. So, it matches every consecutive sequence of alphabets that form words.

Comment: except words(alphabets) can it match numbers or it throws them away?

Comment: @kostaspapadopoulos.. No. It won't match numbers. For matching digit you need `\\d+`. If you really want to learn `Regex`. I suggest you to go through the `Oracle Tutorial on Regex`. It describes each of them. And there are numerous resources on Regex on internet. You can search them.